# - How to exclude conditional repeats in a column?

Tags: r

I want to delete in a column of my dataframe remarks that repeat less than 5 times ...

I am viewing in a new_frame the frequency of the obsevations and the amount of groups that formed that column, however I would like this to happen in my df original.

after I use this command and I'll check by checking the remarks count, continue to appear combinations with less than 5 reps and mess up all the info ..

```
df1<-df[!(df$X<5),]

check <- data.frame(table(df1$X))
check[check$Freq < 5,]
```

I want in the end to remove all observations that have less than 5, can anyone help me, please?

## #

the problem is that I have for the same animals different values in the X column in which it was formed by concatenating 5 other df columns. in column X I have combinations of this type (animal 1 = column x = 1 10 2014 1 19, the same animal 1 = column x = 1 10 2015 1 18). I want to clean those animals that are part of combinations that are repeated less than 5 times in column X) I could not reproduce what you just show me the groups and the freq. I have 127 thousand information that when I count the groupings that are based on column X, I get 970 groups, after cleaning (<5) I get 700 combinations with> 5 repetitions ... I want to stay only with the animals that are part of this group of 700 combinations by column X ... I do not know if I could explain it well, sorry ..
if you can help me I'm very in trouble##

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. After you get the frequency table, you can extract the values that had frequency < 5, then use `%in%` to retain only those values in your original `df` that match with those names.

```
df[df$X %in% check$Var1[check$Freq < 5], ]
```